# How to get all visible variables for a certain method in JDT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I want to develop an Eclipse plug-in which get all visible variables for a specific method.
For example:

```
public class testVariable {  
    String test1;  
    Object test2;
        void method_test1(){
            int test3,test4;
        }
        void method_test2(){
            int test5,test6;
            //get variable here!!!!
        }
}
```

I just want to get visible variable is: `test1, test2,test5,test6` in method `method_test2`. What can I do?

Comment: Please give more detail about your question. No `method_test2` in your code above

Comment: What do you mean with visible? do you mean `private`, `protected`, `public` access modifier..

Comment: No! That is scope! In `test5`,`test6` has scope of `method_test2`, and `test3`,`test4` has scope of `method_test1`, therefore, `test3`,`test4` is invisible!

Comment: You wanna know wich variables are accessible from a particular piece of code ? if yes, then : you can have that simply by doing `Ctrl+Space` and moreover : why do you need that ?

Comment: Sorry! My question is unclearly. I'm edited! @benzonico: I want to write plug-in of eclipse jdt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, JDT can be used outside of a plug-in, i.e., it can be used in a stand-alone Java application.

The following code can return the variables you want:

```
public static void parse(char[] str) {
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setSource(str);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

    public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment var) {

        System.out.println("variable: " + var.getName());

        return false;
    }

    public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration md) {

        if (md.getName().toString().equals("method_test2")) {
            md.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
                public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment fd) {
                    System.out.println("in method: " + fd);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

}

The output is:

```
variable: test1
variable: test2
in method: test5
in method: test6
```

Check out more examples at [JDT tutorials](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/best-java-development-tooling-jdt-and-astparser-tutorials/).